# Node.js/Express: mongoose/mongoDB update document with req.body but avoid updating _id field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, insert-update

I am currently trying to update a document based on some _id value. If found, I want to update evreything with req.body, except setting a new _id (I want to avoid, that client can update their _id). So how can I do this? Would I update all fields manually and exclude _id field?
Currently I am doing this:

```
exports.updateDemoStatus = function(req, res) {
    Status.findOneAndUpdate({Demonstrator: req.params.demo_id}, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, status) {
        if (err)
            console.log(status);
        res.json(status);       
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating a document won't change it's `_id` field since it's unique and related to that specific document.

Please refer to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).
As suggested on the Mongoose official docs, if you need full-fledged validation, use the traditional approach of first retrieving the document.